# Dynamic Match Query MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

How would I write one of these expressions dynamically with a variable in nodejs or typescript?

```
$match: {
          date: '9-8-2019',
          "info.tag": "Test"
        }
```

or

```
$match: { 
    $expr: {
      $and:[ { $eq: ["$price_id", "$$id"]}, { $eq: ["$tag", "Test"] }]
    }
}
```

Comment: value is dynamic or static?

Comment: I want to be able to set the $match dynamically.

Comment: Yes, I know that but the date and tag value are dynamic or not?

Comment: Yes I want them to be dynamic. How would you set $tag though?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to say?

Comment: Explain what you actually want.

Comment: var $tag = "Test"

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean to pass TypeScript variables to the query?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try with the help of this

```
$match: {
id: req.body.id,
$and: [{
    createdAt: {
        $gte: new Date(start)
    }
}, {
    createdAt: {
        $lte: new Date(end)
    }
}]
```

},